# mysql trigger is not enforcing before insert trigger

Tags: mysql

i am trying to enforce unique constraints.  i have two tables, with a common column puuid.  The value is unique in both. If a user tries inserting a puuid into table1 and it already exists in table2,  it should prevent me from doing so.  i am not able to get it to work.  heres my query:

```
create table if not exists table1
(puuid varchar(50) not null unique)

create table if not exists table2
(puuid varchar(50) not null unique)

delimiter $$
create trigger temp_trigger
before INSERT
on table2 t2 for each ROW 
BEGIN 
    declare c int,
    select count(*) into c from table1 t1 where t1.puuid = NEW.puuid
    if (c > 0) THEN 
    -- abort insert because puuid cannot be null
    set NEW.puuid = NULL;
    end if;
    
END$$

delimiter;

insert into table1 (puuid)
values ('22')

insert into table2 (puuid)
values ('22')
```

Its still successfully inserting.  what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code had some errors, corrected the code make what you need

but a better way is to used [SIGNAL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)

see the second trigger

> ```
> create table if not exists table1
> (puuid varchar(50) not null unique);
>
> create table if not exists table2
> (puuid varchar(50) not null unique);
> create table if not exists table3
> (puuid varchar(50) not null unique)
> ```

> ```
> create trigger temp_trigger
> before INSERT
> on table2  for each ROW 
> BEGIN 
>     declare c int;
>     select count(*) into c from table1 t1 where t1.puuid = NEW.puuid;
>     if (c > 0) THEN 
>     -- abort insert because puuid cannot be null
>     set NEW.puuid = NULL;
>     end if;
>     
> END;
> ```

> ```
> insert into table1 (puuid)
> values ('22');
> ```

> ```
> insert into table2 (puuid)
> values ('22')
> ```
>
> ```
> Column 'puuid' cannot be null
> ```

> ```
> create trigger temp_trigger2
> before INSERT
> on table3  for each ROW 
> BEGIN 
>     declare c int;
>     select count(*) into c from table1 t1 where t1.puuid = NEW.puuid;
>     if (c > 0) THEN 
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
>           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'id already exists';
>     end if;
>     
> END;
> ```

> ```
> insert into table3 (puuid)
> values ('22')
> ```
>
> ```
> id already exists
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | puuid |
> | :---- |
> | 22    |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | puuid |
> | :---- |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table3;
> ```
>
> ```
> | puuid |
> | :---- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efb3e72a2bd45d941c68b36c1f63e0e1)*